# WordPress error to show tabs in single product

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use woo-commerce for WordPress. And i install it successful, but when open single product. I don't see tabs and reviews and comment.

I edit config like :-

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

and show this error :-

> Notice: Function woocommerce_sort_product_tabs() expects an array as
>   the first parameter. Defaulting to empty array. in
>   D:\AppServ\www\ec\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php
>   on line 974

Where error ?

I Use Last version of WP and WooCommerce

Comment: I think you didn't added product description.. If not than try adding some content in product description.

Comment: i think you are passing argument is empty or string to woocommerce_sort_product_tabs($tabs);

Comment: i fill all data in product page in wp-admin and not show any things

Comment: Product description isn't a requirement. @ZamalekMan, what is on that line?